# Loopback 127.0.0.1 not working in win 7

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-7, operating-system

I am trying to communicate with comms from a server to a client on the same PC. So if I send the word "Hello" from one it appears on the other like a chat program. As I am on one PC I set IP to 127.0.0.1 and port to 7000 although port could be lots of other numbers. When I press to connect it will not connect to local host.

On XP laptop all is OK so something in set-up is not good. I looked at opening Firefox and typed in Local Host it works, tried 127.0.0.1 it works so IIS is working BUT that is not what I want. I looked for files with local host in and find in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc a file called hosts with 127.0.0.1 and IPv6 version ::1 commented out. Uncommented and still nothing works.

Switched off firewall still no good, switched off Virus detection still nothing.

What have I missed how can a chat program talk on loopback in Win7?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are intentionally typing in Local Host separately.  The host "localhost" is what you are after, followed by the appropriate port number.

Example:

http://localhost:7000/url_to_chat

If you have been doing that correctly, then you just need to define two different ports for each app if you are running both on the same machine in Windows 7 and done.

If you are using Visual Studio's IIS Express (recommended as you don't have to run as an admin), all you have to do is specify the port number and create the folder.  You'll then have to run each app.

[image]

Hope that helps.

Try this site for information on how to change your hosts file:

https://bowerwebsolutions.com/how-to-edit-your-local-host-file-for-testing-web-sites/

Comment: Unfortunately no help at all. Not sure you understand the question. I need to get 127.0.0.1 loopback working not LOCALHOST. I do say localhost and IIs is working. I cannot get the chat Server Client to bind to loopback. Maybe you have more suggestions?

Comment: What is the hostname and port number for the client and the server?  What technology are you using for chat?  Can you provide a code sample so we can see more information?  Thanks.

Comment: The easiest would be to point you to  [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12893/TCP-IP-Chat-Application-Using-C)  Here you see the server has IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8000);
Socket newsock = Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                   SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
newsock.Bind(localEndPoint);
newsock.Listen(10);
Socket client = newsock.Accept(); and the client IPEndPoint ipep = 
    new IPEndPoint(Ipaddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8000);